# Custom UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I would like to make `UISplitViewController` customized like on the image below. You can see  that master is navigation controller.

Is this possible to do with `UISplitViewController`?

[image]

Comment: is your app going to be in portrait mode too ?

Comment: First of all, Don't Add Answer(It is not the Answer). Simply Edit your Question. Second, you told in your previous comment that your App follows Landscape mode Only. If you need support in Portrait mode then remember you can always change the Background Image of any of your view. As I told the Game is all about "Dividing your Main Image in Required Parts" !!!

Comment: @Bojan : Have you solved your Question ? If yes then mark the Answer as Accepted. It will increase your Accept Ratio as well as it will be helpful for future visitors also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, What's wrong with that. If your app is for "Landscape Mode Only" then You have to just cut your Image File into 3 Parts and then you can use them easily with Different Controllers of Split Views.

**Answer :** The Game is all about **"Dividing your Main Image in Required Parts"**.

**Like this :**

[image]